# How to include wildcard pattern in foreach statement of Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have some rules in a makefile like below

```
 ...

 $(MODEL_DIR)/2001.model : $(DATA_DIR)/2000.dat
    python fit.py --year 2001 --data-dir $(DATA_DIR) --output-dir $(MODEL_DIR)

 $(MODEL_DIR)/2002.model : $(DATA_DIR)/2000.dat $(DATA_DIR)/2001.dat 
    python fit.py --year 2002 --data-dir $(DATA_DIR) --output-dir $(MODEL_DIR)

 $(MODEL_DIR)/2003.model : $(DATA_DIR)/2000.dat $(DATA_DIR)/2001.dat $(DATA_DIR)/2002.dat 
    python fit.py --year 2003 --data-dir $(DATA_DIR) --output-dir $(MODEL_DIR)

 $(MODEL_DIR)/2004.model : $(DATA_DIR)/2000.dat $(DATA_DIR)/2001.dat $(DATA_DIR)/2002.dat $(DATA_DIR)/2003.dat 
    python fit.py --year 2004 --data-dir $(DATA_DIR) --output-dir $(MODEL_DIR)

 ...
```

This basically specifies that the model for a year depends on data from previous years having been created.

I would like a simpler pattern based rule to make this less prone to copy paste errors. I tried

```
$(MODEL_DIR)/%.model : $(foreach num,$(shell seq 2000 %),$(DATA_DIR)/$(num).dat) 
    python fit.py --year $* --data-dir $(DATA_DIR) --output-dir $(MODEL_DIR)
```

But I get the error

```
seq: invalid floating point argument: %
```

indicating that the wildcard is not being expanded in the shell command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, but such function calls are expanded *before* matching the pattern rule to a target, so `%` has no value to be fed to `seq`. The way to do this kind of calculation in the prerequisite list is by using [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), and escaping each variable with an extra '$' to prevent it being expanded in the first round:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(MODEL_DIR)/%.model : $$(foreach num,$$(shell seq 2000 %),$(DATA_DIR)/$$(num).dat)
    ...
```

Finally, notice that `seq` will give all years up to *and including* the year of the model, so we must remove the last prerequisite:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(MODEL_DIR)/%.model : $$(filter-out $$*.dat,$$(foreach num,$$(shell seq 2000 %),$(DATA_DIR)/$$(num).dat))
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough response! This is exactly what I was looking for